# Force application use before allowing to run another application

Tags: android

Is there any application that forces the user to first run a specific application for a certain period of time, before allowing the user to run any other application?

We want our university students to run an online application before allowing the student to access any other applications. Is there any application that we can use that sets up this conditional usage?

The first program is, specifically, an online resource to instruct the students about unconscious bias, so it would be access to this online resource via Chrome (or other browser) for a certain period of time (say 15 minutes) that would be the necessary trigger to allow the tablet to be used for other purposes.